# How to make this progress bar into a circle javascript vuejs css

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, progress-bar

I have been having the most stressful time making this progress bar into a circle progress bar. I've tried using progressbar.js but that isn't helping me.

html

```
  <div id="myProgress">
    <div id="myBar" v-bind:style="{width: activewidth}">{{activewidth}} done</div>
  </div> <br>
```

js

```
moveBar: function () {
      let numLessons = 1
      for (let i = 0; i < this.opts.lessonsArr.length; i++) {
        numLessons++
      }
      // this.numComp is the percentage of the bar
      this.numComp = (numLessons % 5).toString()
      console.log('numLeft', this.numComp)
      // this.activewidth determines the % completed, so the green bar 
      this.activewidth = (this.numComp * 20 + '%').toString()
      console.log('thiswidth', this.activewidth)
    }
```

css

```
#myProgress {
  width: 95%;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#myBar {
  width: 30%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  text-align: center; /* To center it horizontally (if you want) */
  line-height: 20px; /* To center it vertically */
  color: white;

}
```

what i have now:

image of progress bar:

[image: image of progress bar]

this is in vuejs, and in a big project :( please help me do this in pure css (if possible)

Comment: i forgot to mention that i simply want a circle progress bar with the % in the center

Comment: is this what you are looking for ?? http://anthonyterrien.com/demo/knob/

Comment: Knobjs .. Give that a try

Comment: @ChandraShekhar kindof but not jquery is it possible to do this in css?

Comment: it doesnt have to be animated nor anything. it can be static